# python beautifulsoup extract text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract `Manufacturer #` and `PAW11295` from below html source code and got stuck. Appreciate any suggestions.

```
soupTest.find("div",id = "AddnInfo")
Out[121]: 
<div id="AddnInfo">
<h3>Additional Info</h3>
<p>
<p class="sknText"><label>“R”Web#:</label> <span class="value">215904</span>   </p>
<p class="skuText"><label>SKU:</label> <span class="value">B7958C02</span>    </p>
<p class="upc"><label>UPC/EAN/ISBN:</label> <span class="value">092317112958</span></p>
<p><label>Manufacturer #:</label> PAW11295</p>
<p><label>Product Weight:</label>2.2 pounds</p>
<p><label>Product Dimensions (in inches):</label>12.7 x 10.1 x 5.4</p>
</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Okay, how is that working out for you? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach should work. It takes the 5th `<p>` element and gets the `<label>` text. It then removes this and display the stripped text for the whole `<p>` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div id="AddnInfo">
<h3>Additional Info</h3>
<p>
<p class="sknText"><label>“R”Web#:</label> <span class="value">215904</span>   </p>
<p class="skuText"><label>SKU:</label> <span class="value">B7958C02</span>    </p>
<p class="upc"><label>UPC/EAN/ISBN:</label> <span class="value">092317112958</span></p>
<p><label>Manufacturer #:</label> PAW11295</p>
<p><label>Product Weight:</label>2.2 pounds</p>
<p><label>Product Dimensions (in inches):</label>12.7 x 10.1 x 5.4</p>
</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div = soup.find('div', {'id':'AddnInfo'})
p = div.find_all('p')[4]
label = p.find('label')
manufacturer = label.text
label.extract()
id = p.get_text(strip=True)
print manufacturer
print id
```

Which would display:

```
Manufacturer #:
PAW11295
```

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. It works. I am curious why after `label.extract()`, `p` became `<p> PAW11295</p>` and can't get it back to `<p><label>Manufacturer #:</label> PAW11295</p>`? I checked the office documentation but still got confused.

Comment: `extract()` removes the tag, it is like a delete command. If you need to preserve the html, you could make a copy before doing this.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this.
First select the outer P tag. Then select all the inner P tags. Then reference the individual P tag you want, in this case the fourth one.

```
infoDiv = soupTest.find("div",id = "AddnInfo")
outerPs = infoDiv.p  # isolate the outer <P>
innerPs = outerPs.find_all('p')  # returns a list of the inner <P>s
manufacturer_number = innerPs[3].string  # you will have to trim the <label>
manufacturer_code = innerPs[3].label.string  # will need trimming
```